# Find an equation of the sequence $1, 3, 12, 60, 360, 2520, \cdots $.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, sequence-of-function, pattern-recognition

**Proof:**
By rule of formation
$$a_1=1=\frac{(1+1)!}{2}$$

$$a_2=3=\frac{(1+2)!}{2}$$

$$a_3=12=\frac{(1+3)!}{2}$$

$$a_4=60=\frac{(1+4)!}{2}$$

$$a_5=360=\frac{(1+5)!}{2}$$

$$a_6=2520=\frac{(1+6)!}{2}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$a_n=\frac{(1+n)!}{2}$$

Is there any other way?

Would appreciate your guidance.

Comment: This is one possible (and the most plausible) formula, the so-called "reasonable guess". There is no general way to find such formulas , and no matter which are the next entries, a formula could be constructed (for example with polynomial interpolation). Therefore we either need context or find a formula that "probably" is the solution.

Comment: Note that such pattern exercises , since usually no context is given , are not math. They are often used for intelligence tests however.

Comment: I don’t see what this has to do with the rule of formation.

Comment: @peter It is an important skill for a mathematician to have, so I’d call it math, even if it is never the final result of a mathematical proof.

Comment: "Is there any other way" : what "way" did you use to derive this? You have directly recognized it from a familiar sequence, so it is a way that is somewhat like "reducing to familiarity" and that's what a lot of pattern recognition is, isn't it? I mean, you do have standard techniques, perhaps (for polynomial type relations, consider the difference of successive terms, for exponential type relations consider the ratio of consecutive terms) for example, take the ratio of consecutive terms above and you get $3,4,5,6,7,...$ which should not be difficult to recognize.

Comment: I'd also like clarification on what the "rule of formation" is. It seems to be something similar to what I'm talking about, but I can't be too sure so it will be good to know. Whatever, basically while spotting patterns look for ratios/differences of consecutive terms, sometimes you need to play with square roots and stuff, sometimes a floored quantity of a real number pattern, sometimes primes come in, so you've got to be flexible with these concepts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Is there any other way?" Any other way for what? The n-th term is a constant times the factorial of $n+1,$ and the factorial function this has no exact closed-form formula that equals it. You could approximate it by [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), or [other methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Versions_suitable_for_calculators), but this will only be an approximation; it won't give you the exact value in the sequence.

Comment: Thanks, got it! Yes, I was mean to ask about the general(or nth) term of the given sequence. I have understood now. Thanks a million.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Why is my answer incorrect?

Comment: Boh? I delete ones.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a sequence of integers like $1, 3, 12, 60, 360, 2520$ and you want to know what is a likely extension of it... consult the
[On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org).  Type your sequence in the search box, and see what happens!

In this case, we get 4 sequences that match it.  But [A00170](http://oeis.org/A001710) is the most likely.  (The other three turned out to be essentially this one anyway.)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I got it. I was confused to find the general term of the given sequence because you see it is a weird type of sequence.